# How to insert componets in a product like apple website?

Tags: magento2

I wanna insert adictionals options in a product and increment the price. How make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom options

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

or create a configurable products

> (if you want to manage stock based on options then u can create
> configurable product with simple products as per above link)

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

accept solution if helps you.

Comment: thanx for upvote. you can mark as a solution if its work for you.so someone can reach the answer :)